# Simplified Android SAX XML Parsing Problem

Tags: android, xml, sax

I have seen the methods of simplified Android SAX XML Parsing.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

I have parsed the data, but I can't seem to get it to display to the screen using looped TextViews.

This is my AndroidSaxFeedParser class...

```
public class AndroidSaxFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser{

final MagazineList magazineList = new MagazineList();

    protected AndroidSaxFeedParser(String magazinefeaturedURL) {
        super(magazinefeaturedURL);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<MagazineList> parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        RootElement root = new RootElement("maintag");

        final List<MagazineList> magazines = new ArrayList<MagazineList>();
        Element item = root.getChild("item");

        item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){

            @Override
            public void end() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazines.add(magazineList);
            }

        });

        item.getChild("name").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            @Override
            public void end(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setName(name);
            }
        });


        item.getChild("imgurl").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String imgurl) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setImgurl(imgurl);
            }
        });

        item.getChild("date").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String date) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setDate(date);
            }
        });

        item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String description) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setDescription(description);
            }
        });

        item.getChild("price").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String price) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setPrice(price);
            }
        });

        item.getChild("download").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String download) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                magazineList.setDownload(download);
            }
        });


        return magazines;
    }

}
```

This is my object model class...

```
public class MagazineList {

private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> imgurl = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> download = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public ArrayList<String> getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.add(name);
}

public ArrayList<String> getImgurl(){
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl){
    this.imgurl.add(imgurl);
}

public ArrayList<String> getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date.add(date);
}

public ArrayList<String> getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price.add(price);
}

public ArrayList<String> getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description.add(description);
}

public ArrayList<String> getDownload() {
    return download;
}

public void setDownload(String download) {
    this.download.add(download);
}
}
```

The question now is... how to make it display on the main Activity?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MagazineList magazineList = null;
private List<MagazineList> magazines = null;



    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);


    TextView name[];
    TextView imgurl[];
    TextView date[];
    TextView description[];
    TextView price[];
    TextView download[];

    AndroidSaxFeedParser saxparser = new  AndroidSaxFeedParser(<my website>);
    magazines = saxparser.parse();
    for(MagazineList magazineList : magazines){
         name = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];
         imgurl = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];
         date = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];
         description = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];
         price = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];
         download = new TextView[magazineList.getName().size()];


    (Supposingly I should get my data from here... What's next? Perhaps I have some syntax errors when declaring TextViews, I'm not sure. Please help out.)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, I'm no Java expert, but I've never seen anything like what you're doing with those TextViews. That's array notation.

<strike>Try this instead (assuming the parsing code is working correctly)</strike>

Wait, I'm COMPLETELY thrown off by what you're doing here with the MagazineList class. Okay, first things, for the TextViews, you're going to want to use something like this:

```
name = new TextView(this);
name.setText(/*your magazinelist getter for name*/);
name.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.addView(name);
```

Are these going into a list? What are you ultimately doing with them? If you're just trying to make sure the content is getting parsed, just run the debugger and check the magazinelist object after running the parsing.

As far as your MagazineList class...maybe I'm misunderstanding, but really you should just have a Magazine class, that defines a single magazine and its name, date, etc., then you can use an `ArrayList<Magazine>` to create a list of magazines. Then you can use a foreach loop to iterate through them, or adapt them to a custom ListView.

Example Magazine class:

```
public class Magazine {

private String name, imgurl, date, price, description, download;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImgurl(){
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl){
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDownload() {
    return download;
}

public void setDownload(String download) {
    this.download = download;
}
}
```

Then you just need to extend an ArrayAdapter that'll take in your ArrayList or Magazine[] and display it into a ListView.